# jQuery: how to get the id of a div (with a class named "hidden")

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

can you help me please ?

I'm searching for a solution to get an id from a hidden div and interact the id in an AJAX query when a click is happened

**PHP code :**

```
while ( $contents_print = mysqli_fetch_array( $req_print ) ) {
echo '
        <div class="post print" id="staggered-test">
            <img src="../00_sources/images/upload/pic_min/' . $contents_print[ 'pic_min' ] . '" alt="' . $contents_print[ 'pic_min' ] . '"/>
                <div class="post-content">          
                    <a href="#modal" class="modal-action modal-trigger">Détail</a>
                    <div class="row"><blockquote>' . $contents_print[ 'detail_projet' ] . '</blockquote></div>
                </div>
            <div class="post-content valign-wrapper"><h4 class="header center">' . $contents_print[ 'nom_projet' ] . '</h4></div>
        </div>
    ';

echo '<div class="hidden" id="'.$contents_print[ 'id_projet' ].'"></div>';
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$( document ).ready( function () {
  $(".post").siblings('div:hidden').attr("id").click(function() {
    var url_id = $(this).attr('id');
    //alert(url_id);
  });

  $.ajax({
    url: 'core/libs/contents-services.php?action=getFilterContent&id='+url_id,
    type: "get",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function ( reponse ) {
      $( '#modal' ).html( reponse );
      url_id = reponse.url_id;
    }
  });

  // the "href" attribute of the modal trigger must specify the modal ID that wants to be triggered
  $( '.modal' ).modal();
});
```

May be I'm missing something, my code doesn't work

Please help me. Thanks a lot !

Comment: What do you mean by hidden id? Its from the last line of your code?

Comment: How can you click on a hidden `<div>`? Explain the expected behavior

Comment: .attr(‘id’) returns the div’s id which is not a suitable object to set a click handler on.

Comment: @ShahariaAzam i put the id from mysql request in a hidden div, in this way i can use it from ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `data-` attribute to store the project id on your link

```
'<a class="modal-action" data-id_projet="'.$contents_print[ 'id_projet' ].'"...>'
```

Then use that to reference the modal container

```
$('.post .modal-action').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id_projet= $(this).data('id_projet');
    var $hidennDiv = $('#' +id_projet);
    // do your ajax and whatever you want to do with the hidden div
})
```

beyond this it is really not clear what objective is

Comment: Works perfectly !!!!!!!! That's what i was searching since 7 days ! thanks a lot !!!! And all of you to take time to answer to me

Answer (score 0):

First, change the siblings selector to use the class selection like this:

```
.siblings('div.hidden')
```

Next, you are using `attr("id")` to get the ID of the element, which returns a string, and adding a click event handler to a string, which is also not supported.   You can do the following in one statement; i'm going to do it in two to illustrate it:

```
var id = $(".post").siblings('div.hidden').attr("id");
$("#" + id).click(function() {
  ..
});
```

The id variable gets the ID, and then using #ID syntax selection in jQuery to match by ID, a click event can then be applied to the hidden element.

Comment: Won't get instance specific `id`. Will always return first `.hidden` id in the page

Comment: @James no...the elements are generated in a `while` loop so there will be many of them in the page that are hidden and that selector will create collection of all of them

Comment: @charlietfl I mean..assuming the rest works and elements with class hidden do get hidden, is there a reason to switch from :hidden to .hidden (this answer seems to focus on the problem being the use of pseudo instead of class selector)

Comment: I got this message : A bunch of text ?

Comment: @James to me is more about isolating the correct instance. OP needs to do some clarification though of exactly what they are trying to accomplish

Comment: Yeah it should be wrapped with an outer DIV to isolate each row.

Answer (score 0):

You have a line that assigns event handlers, which is currently broken:

```
$(".post").siblings('div:hidden').attr("id").click(function() {
```

simply remove `.attr('id')` as it makes no sense there.

```
$(".post").siblings('div:hidden').click(function() {
```

The second problem is now you have assigned a bunch of click handlers to hidden divs, so how is the user going to click them?

Answer (score -2):

You could do something like this:

```
$(".post").find(':hidden').each(function(a, el){
    console.log(a, $(el).attr("id"));
})
```

[Code](https://jsfiddle.net/benjamingoek/qh57Laae/)

Comment: The hidden class is a sibling, not descendant of the post class

Comment: than just change "$(".post").find(':hidden').each..." to "$(".post").siblings('div:hidden').each..."?! :)